# Reading request parameters in Google App Engine with Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, parameters, httpwebrequest

I'm modifying the default project that Eclipse creates when you create a new project with Google Web Toolkit and Google App Engine. It is the GreetingService sample project.

How can I read a request parameter in the client's .java file?

For example, the current URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8887/MyProj.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1&foo=bar` and I want to use something like `request.getParameter("foo") == "bar"`.

I saw that the documentation mentions the [Request](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html) class for Python, but I couldn't find the equivalent for Java. It's listed as being in the `google.appengine.ext.webapp` package, but if I try importing that into my .java file (with a `com.` prefix), it says that it can't resolve the `ext` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using [Window.Location](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html) via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515052/how-can-i-get-the-current-url-in-google-web-toolkit-via-client-side-java-code/4515148#4515148):

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;

// ...

Window.Location.getParameter("foo") // == "bar"
```

Note that:

> Location is a very simple wrapper, so not all browser quirks are hidden from the user.

Answer (score 4):

[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Requests_and_Servlets) uses the [Java Servlet API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html).

GWT's [RemoteServiceServlet](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RemoteServiceServlet.html) provides access to the request through:

`HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();`

from which you can call either `request.getQueryString()`, and interpret the query string any way you desire, or you can call `request.getParameter("foo")`

Comment: Hmm... I'm able to `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;` but I'm not sure how to access the variable of that type. My `onModuleLoad()` takes no arguments and I don't see any other variables of that type.

Comment: I updated my answer. Does the GreetingService extend RemoteServiceServlet?

Comment: Nope, it just `implements EntryPoint`.

Comment: See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej1/ Listing 5 vs Listing 8

Comment: Sorry - this answer is for server side, not client side. Your mentions of GAE and requests threw me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.net.URL` to parse the URL and then `String.split()` to parse the query string.

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8887/MyProj.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1&foo=bar");
String query[] = url.getQuery().split("&");
String foo = null;
for (String arg : query) {
  String s[] = arg.split("=");
  if (s[0].equals("foo"))
    System.out.println(s[1]);
}
```

See http://ideone.com/Da4fY

Comment: Thanks for the code sample, but the URL should be taken from the current URL the user is viewing... not a static string.

Comment: @Senseful You should be able to easily plonk in a string variable. Just remember that if you can't be sure of the validity of the URL, you should do proper exception handling for when say you have the query string `foo&bar`

Comment: I'm looking through the documentation to try to find out how to get the current URL... [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015442/how-to-get-the-current-server-url-of-appengine-app) didn't help. If you know how, could you please update the answer?

Comment: @Senseful Oh, you mean the app engine URL. You should probably ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @marcog: alright, I asked it as a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515052/how-can-i-get-the-current-url-in-google-app-engine-via-client-side-java-code). Thanks for your help.

Comment: It doesn't let me use java.net.URL in the client.

Comment: @Senseful You can do a `url.split("?")[1]` to get the query string.